How to Keep a Constant Output Voltage While Using MPPT?
I wanted to design a solar energy management system that utilizes a 12-volt, 60-watt solar panel to charge two 12-volt, 12 Ah batteries efficiently. The system is aimed at optimizing energy storage and transfer by using a single buck-boost converter and a relay-controlled switching mechanism.
System Overview:
Solar Panel: The 12V, 60W solar panel acts as the primary energy source.
Batteries: Two identical 12V, 12Ah batteries (labeled as B1 and B2) store the energy.
Buck-Boost Converter: A single converter is used to adjust the voltage for charging the batteries, ensuring they receive the required 13.6V for optimal charging.
Relay-Controlled Switching: Relays are employed to manage the energy flow between the solar panel and the batteries, allowing flexible control over the charging process.
Charging Process:
Step 1 - Solar Panel to Battery B2: The solar panel first charges Battery B2 through the converter.
Step 2 - Solar Panel to Battery B1: Once B2 is fully charged, the energy flow is redirected to charge Battery B1.
Step 3 - Battery B1 to Battery B2: After Battery B1 is fully charged, it discharges energy back into Battery B2 as needed.
The biggest challenge I faced was trying to use MPPT (Maximum Power Point Tracking) in the converter, as I don’t fully understand how it works. I know the algorithm tracks the maximum input power, but I’m unsure how it does so. If I gather feedback from both the input and output voltage and current to track the maximum power and then adjust the duty cycle accordingly, how does the output voltage remain constant? Since I always need a fixed output voltage of 14V for battery charging, which is the converter’s output voltage, I don’t understand how the adjustments to track the maximum power at the input don’t affect the output voltage.

Are the batteries lead-acid? (or perhaps LiFePO4?) Is there a reason you do not want to charge them in parallel?

The batteries we use in our project are LiFePO4, each with a capacity of 12V and 12Ah. The battery we refer to as "B2" is a mobile battery, which will detach from the solar panel as needed and be used on a vehicle. This vehicle will perform daily tasks, such as collecting trash on the beach.

Do you have a particular MPPT chip/module that you are using, or need to use? MPPT works by adjusting the input impedance of the buck/boost converter to maximize output from the solar panel. If, however, the converter is producing the right voltage, but the MPPT chip/module wants to output more current than the batteries can tolerate for charging, it may be possible to disable the MPPT function temporarily depending upon the chip/module. (cont)

(cont) IMHO it is easier to let the sun heat up the solar panel than to extract maximum power, when not needed, and then have to dissipate some of that extra power elsewhere to prevent battery damage.

I haven’t been able to find a suitable MPPT chip or module for my project, and even if such chips exist, I haven’t been able to source them locally. Instead, I plan to design the MPPT system myself using Arduino.

The whole point of MPPT is that you have a load that can accept variable amounts of current. In other words, you can't charge a battery at constant voltage or constant current if you want to use MPPT -- you need to let the charge rate vary to match the power output of the solar array.

But isn’t this harmful to the battery? Don’t we need to charge batteries with a specific maximum voltage? For example, for LiFePO4 batteries, the maximum charging voltage is typically around 3.65V per cell. Exceeding this voltage can damage the battery or reduce its lifespan.

Yes, but you can also charge at a lower voltage. Once you hit the maximum voltage of the battery, you can no longer do MPPT. Or you can dump the excess power into another load -- a second battery, a water heater, etc.

Let’s say I have a 12V, 60W solar panel connected to an MPPT converter. The MPPT provides an output of 15V, 4A, but the output voltage is not stable. I use this output to charge a battery, even though the battery ideally requires a constant 14V for safe charging.
When the battery's voltage reaches 14V, I cut off the power to prevent overcharging. I chose these specific input and output voltage values as examples to understand whether the MPPT concept works this way. Is it correct that I don’t need a constant output voltage from the MPPT to charge the battery?

You continue to conflate the concepts of "maximum voltage" and "constant voltage". You need to understand the distinction between the two before we can make forward progress.

PV panels behave as a voltage limited current source... or a current limited voltage source, which is the same. Their I-V curve looks like this:

The main issue is, any given level of illumination corresponds to a value of maximum current. Basically, each photon kicks one electron to a higher energy level, so the amount of electrons per second (ie, current) you can get is proportional to the amount of photons per second (ie, illumination).
If you don't draw enough current, you're not using all the available power. This is what happens in the part of the IV curve left of "Pmp" (Point of Maximum Power). In this case, increasing current does not cause voltage to drop, and results in more power.
But if you draw too much current, as shown on the right side of Pmp point, voltage will drop very fast, resulting in much reduced output power. In this case, to get more power, you must draw less current, letting voltage rise back to Vmp.
There are many different MPPT algorithms. The main difference is how they handle shading. If you have many panels in series, and some are shaded and others receive full sunlight, the IV curve of the series combination will be different from the one shown above. Here's an example:

This needs a smarter algo to find the maximum power point.
Most algos use a mix of:

"Perturb and Observe"

It constantly modifies the PV current a little bit around the current operating point, and measures resulting power. If power increases by changing current in one direction, then it will update the current set point in this direction. This tracks a local maximum in the power curve.

Full scan

Periodically, or when triggered by some events like a sudden loss of power, it will scan the whole I/V curve to discover all the bumps, and pick the best one.
If you do not wire panels in series, then this is less of a problem.
If you use a DC-DC converter to charge a battery:

Voltage is set by the battery itself, not the DC-DC. It will slowly rise as the battery charges.

Your DC-DC should have current output, not voltage output.

The DC-DC still needs to monitor voltage in order to avoid overcharging the battery and keep the panel at maximum power.


Basically, you need a current output DC-DC, whose output current is adjusted to avoid overcharging the battery. When the final charging voltage is reached, current should be reduced. This can be implemented either by shutting down the DC/DC when target voltage is reached, or setting a maximum current according to the difference between current battery voltage and full charge voltage. As voltage gets closer to the end of charge voltage, current tapers off to zero.
The above sets a maximum output current. Actual output current is then adjusted by the MPPT algorithm to remain on the maximum power point.
Considering your use, which if I understand correctly is a solar charging station with fixed battery for a mobile battery-powered vehicle, I'd use:

Off the shelf MPPT battery charger to charge the fixed battery: Victron makes many models for 12V batteries, for example. This will save a lot of time.

Buck-boost battery charger between fixed battery and mobile battery when it is plugged.


Rather than a buck-boost converter, it should be simpler to use higher voltage panels (more panels in series) and a buck converter.

MPPT means Maximum Power Point Tracking. The algorithm assumes that all the power put out from the panels can be absorbed by a load. If the load can't absorb that power, and "can't" means that you choose not to absorb the power so as not to overcharge the batteries, then you switch off MPPT mode.
When you are charging batteries, you generally have at least two stages depending on chemistry.
An initial stage where most of the charging takes place, where the batteries define the voltage, and the charger outputs a current. If it's a limited current charger, it drives the programmed current. If it's a limited power charger, which MPPT is, the power is limited by the panels, then it drives I = power_available/battery_voltage, by the way its SMPS output converter works. If it turns out that I available is too high for the battery, then you must switch off MPPT.
The next stage is typically a constant voltage top-off, where the charger defines the voltage, and the battery takes the current it wants at that voltage. If the battery is trying to take less power than the MPPT is delivering, then you must switch off the MPPT. If the battery can take more power than is available, then the battery voltage drops and we have gone back to limited current charging, keep the MPPT enabled.
